# Check if Associated View is blank in Dynamic CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

In CRM Online on a customer form is there anyway that you can check if the Associated View for Assets is blank? And if its blank change a field value based on it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript, 2 ways:

1. The associated grid is showing records related to your primary record. You can perform the same query the grid is doing using REST which will tell you if there are any records. You can then count the records, and change the field value as required. This approach is better if there are records in the database but which aren't shown in the view for some reason, e.g. view filters.
2. Access the [Grid objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932126.aspx) data using `getRows()`. As above you can then count the records, and change the field value as required. The downside of this is I believe those methods only give you access to the records shown on the form (and not any hidden by filters but still in the database) - but I don't think that that will be a problem here.

Worth bearing in mind that this approach only works client side, e.g. someone has to be actually looking at the form.

If you need to cover the a non-client side approach, e.g. workflows creating records, then you should probably look at plugin development so the changes can be performed server side.

As a side if you just want a simple count shown on form you then you should probably look at [Calculated Fields and in particular Rollup fields](http://www.powerobjects.com/2014/11/17/calculated-fields-in-dynamics-crm-2015/). You might also be able to run further client side JavaScript from the count.